# result prints undefined after invoking a new method

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to loop though all users data in my mongo database and check and see if an email is in the database. The loop currently works and correctly identifies if an email is in a database but the problem is once I verify the email exist I get the id of the same object and use `findById()` to find the specific object the email was found in then update it. Once I find the object when I try and print the result I got from the first `find()` it logs undefined but when I log it before the `findById()` method it logs the result without no problem. Why is this happening and how can I log the previous result after invoking  `findById()`. Take a look at the comments on my code to understand the question better. Thanks in advance.

```js
const Users = require('pathToSchema')

const email = 'test@gmail.com'

Users.find()
  .then(async(result) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      if (result[i].email == email) {
        //this prints result successfully
        console.log(result[i])
        Users.findById(result[i].id)
          .then((result2) => {
            //this prints undefiend
            console.log(result[i])
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
          })
      } else {
        if (i === result.length - 1) {
          console.log('email not found')
        }
      }
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

Comment: First you can query mongodb just for that email. You do no have to scroll through each record in JS.

Comment: @RachitAnand didn't know that. I used to do that with mysql. Will look into it.

Comment: you can do something like Users.find({email: 'test@gmail.com'})

Comment: @RachitAnand yeah I did that. My question is though can I update the object containing that email without having to call ```find()``` again?

Comment: Please update your question to reflect what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code snippet it looks like you are trying to print a value from `result` and not `result2`. `result` is not available inside the findById() method callback handler.

Comment: why isn't ```result``` not available inside the ```findById()``` its scope is higher?

Comment: I think it's because you write a method inside `findById()` which has it's own argument passed (`result2`) but you don't pass it `result` anywhere.

Comment: Oh, and it may have to do with the fact that that request is asynchronous and scopes can get weird with asynchronous methods.

Comment: yeah that's probably it. I switched to querying the database so im not running to the problem anymore. I will just delete the question. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Continuing the discussion from the comments, you can use the `findOneAndUpdate` method in mongodb to find a user with a given email and update. With this, you will not have to find the user before you update. You can do that in a single DB command.

```
Users.findOneAndUpdate({email: 'test@gmail.com'},{updates},{options});
```

This will return the original document before update. If you need the updated document in the response, pass `returnNewDocument: true` in the options.

Link to the documentation for this function
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/